# Arcgis javascript api not working in IE 11 (js api 1.6)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, internet-explorer

I have a html with ArcGIS js api, it working in lower version (say IE 7) but not working in IE11,. Is it because my js api version is too low? How can I make it work?

The related code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head  >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Data Creation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="readXML.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="CALENDAR\CalendarControl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="Scripts\JScript_webpage.js"></script>
<link href="CALENDAR\CalendarControl.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/1.6/js/dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"/>
<script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/

+sfgRmluamFuX1R5cGU9amF2YV9zY3JpcHQmRmluamFuX0xhbmc9dGV4dC9qYXZhc2NyaXB0+/?v=1.6" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/vbscript" language="VBScript" src="Scripts\VBScript_webpage.vbs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function Submit_Click(objForm)
{

if(Validate(objForm))
{
  if (document.data.radio[0].checked)
    {
        Data_NEW();
        objForm.reset();
    }
    else if (document.data.radio[1].checked)
    {
        Data_EDIT();
        objForm.reset();
    }
}
}

function SaveAsDraft_Click(objForm)
{

if(Validate(objForm))
{
 SaveAsDraft();
 objForm.reset();

}
}

function TestVerify(objf)
{
  var path = objf.elements["Data_file"]
  var filepath = path.value;
  filepath = ChangethePath(filepath)
  Verify(objf,filepath);
}
```

The function of Submit_click and SaveAsDraft_click totally no response. Any advice?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to contain the JS API version in use

Answer (score 1):

Try the sandboxed sample in [IE11](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=map_simple).

This worked because the page has loaded as a web URL.

Suggest you to set up a web server like IIS, host your files in a virtual directory, and test the application using `http://` instead of `file://`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your version of the ArcGIS JavaScript API probably will not work with Internet Explorer 11. [According to ESRI](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/01/02/arcgis-api-for-javascript-version-3-8-released/), version 3.8 is the first to support IE 11. Currently, [version 3.14 supports IE 7 and up](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/).

There have been a lot of changes since the v. 1.6. The API introduced Dojo's AMD modules, and most of the examples will use a new logic that may break your existing code. Also, Dojo has swapped out a number of controls and components. It's a good idea to look at [the samples](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/) to see how to load the API into your application.

Comment: Hello raykendo, thanks a lot for the clarification.